# style.marginTop = window.innerHeight does not works?

Tags: javascript

`window.innerHeight` does not works for `document.getElementById("pic").style.marginTop`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anirban Bhui</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img id="pic" src="logonit.png">
    <script>
    document.getElementById("pic").style.marginTop = window.innerHeight;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bjwgtesw/

Comment: @SrinivasPai: it works, but why to set `h` when you can use `innerHeight` directly?

Answer (score 3):

In CSS you need to have unit, in this case pixels.

```
document.getElementById("pic").style.marginTop = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fn1s4hvu/